# Header at baseline next to an image

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment

I defined the headmark over `\ihead[]{\headmark}` and an image over `\ohead[\Logo]{\Logo}` with the use of koma script. Now I´ve got the problem, that the `\headmark` is not at the baseline of the head. I helped me by defining `\ihead[]{\vphantom{\Logo}\headmark}`, but that gives different headers on scrplain and scrheadings. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
    adieresis={ä},
    germandbls={ß},
    Euro={€},
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[  automark
            , headsepline
            , plainheadsepline
           ]{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\addtolength{\headheight}{1.2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-1.2cm}

\ihead[]{\vphantom{\Logo}\\\headmark}
\ohead[\Logo]{\Logo}

\newcommand{\Logo}{\rule{3cm}{1cm}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the `\ihead` to the baseline of the header?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add a linebreak to the arguments of `\ohead`:

```
\ihead[]{\vphantom{\Logo}\\\headmark}
\ohead[\\\Logo]{\\\Logo}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d like to have the chapter name a bit lower than the logo. So I tested a little bit and got this solution:

```
\ihead[\vspace*{\dimexpr\the\headheight-\baselineskip}]
      {\vspace*{\dimexpr\the\headheight-2\baselineskip}\\\headmark}
```